How to fix infinite loop from overlapping rectangles?
I'm using an approach from this article (the "Separation Behaviour" section) for dispersing overlapping rectangles. It "iteratively move[s] all the rectangles simultaneously at a certain velocity which is determined by how they overlap with other rectangles." (Note that I'm moving rectangles only vertically.)
I have two types of rectangles: real and virtual. Virtual rectangles are disallowed from moving (and are transparent in the image below). My problem is that, with a certain arrangement of rectangles, my implementation infinitely loops. Just one real rectangle ('Cell Vector') is intersecting three virtual rectangles ('Frame.015', 'Frame.013', 'Frame.012'), and flip-flops between movement amounts.
After dispersing all other real rectangles, this is what it stays as, indefinitely, with nothing moving:


def rect_overlap_velocity(rect1, vectors):
    vec = Vector((0, 0))
    count = 0

    v1 = vectors[rect1]
    centre = (v1[0] + v1[1]) / 2

    for rect2, v2 in vectors.items():
        if rect1 != rect2 and rectangles_overlap(v1, v2):
            vec += ((v2[0] + v2[1]) / 2) - centre
            count += 1

    if not count:
        return vec

    # vec.x = 0
    vec /= count
    vec.negate()
    vec.normalize()

    return vec


def disperse_rectangles():
    real_rectangles = get_real_rectangles()
    vectors = get_rect_vectors(real_rectangles)

    pairs = [(vectors[r1], vectors[r2])
      for r1, r2 in combinations(vectors, 2)
      if r1 in real_rectangles or r2 in real_rectangles]

    while any(rectangles_overlap(v1, v2) for v1, v2 in pairs):
        for rect in real_rectangles:
            tr, bl = vectors[rect]
            vec = rect_overlap_velocity(rect, vectors)
            tr.y += vec.y
            bl.y += vec.y

(Possibly useful info): in rect_overlap_velocity(), If I set the vector's X to 0 before normalising, each iteration flip-flops between 1.0 and -1.0 (forever). But if I don't, it oscillates over a larger period (but still to the point where no progress is ever made):
0.9677687883377075
-0.04892580956220627
-0.04962211474776268
-0.0503283366560936
-0.05104447528719902
-0.051770735532045364
-0.05250733345746994
-0.05325426161289215
-0.054011743515729904
-0.05477996915578842
-0.0555589534342289
-0.056349121034145355
-0.05715003237128258
-0.05796253681182861
-0.05878620222210884
-0.059621673077344894
-0.060468729585409164
-0.06132778525352478
-0.06219884753227234
0.9677560329437256 
...  

Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Please make your example runnable by adding all the details required for us to run it, including a minimal data set that generates the problem you describe.

It would seem to me that separation behavior is only guaranteed if there are no fixed rectangles. Like you've discovered, rectangles could be pushed in an infinite cycle.
What would you want to happen when a piece is amid lots of virtual rectangles? Always go up? Once you decide what you want, I imagine the solution will fall into place.
Edit: maybe you could say, a moving rectangle will continue to move in the direction dictated by the first virtual rectangle until it is no longer touching any virtual rectangles? So, it would get pushed by virtual rectangle #1, then phase through the other 2?
